# In batch scripts how to "skip empty arguments"?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

*Example script call.bat*

```
echo %1.txt %2.txt %3.txt
```

**a) Now, if I call it with**

```
c:\>call Huey Dewey Louie
```

it will print out

```
Huey.txt Dewey.txt Louie.txt
```

**b) If I call it with**

```
c:\>call Huey Dewey
```

it will print out

```
Huey.txt Dewey.txt .txt
```

**How do I make it skip that last part, if I haven't given %3?** (of course, the number of arguments can be more than three, ... let's say 8 or nine).

Comment: I advise against naming a batch file CALL.BAT (or any other existing command name!)

Comment: @dbenham - Yeah, good point ... it is not really called that. 'twas just this example, cause I was lazy to think of anything better.

Answer (score 2):

call.bat

```
:label
echo %1.txt
SHIFT
if not "%1" == "" goto label
```

Is this what you're looking for ?
You'll probably want to set off the echo of commands so put before each command "@" or put "@echo off" at the begining of your script.

Comment: But that would require 9 labels for 9 optional arguments, no?

Comment: What do you mean by 9 optionals arguments ?

Comment: Well, I can call the script with "call one two three" (three arguments), but I can also call it with "call one two" or just "call one" (one argument). Not all %1 ... %9 will be given. So, if I have 9 possible arguments by your script, I would have to write 9 possible labels.

Comment: Not really. The SHIFT cmd will replace %1 with %2, %2 with %3, ... so it will accept 1, 2, 3... or 9 arguments. You should try it. For example : Given %1=the, %2=quick, %3=brown
SHIFT
will result in %1=quick, %2=brown
A second 
SHIFT
will result in %1=brown

Comment: No, delannoyk's answer works as shown; there's no need for more labels (look up what the SHIFT command does). However, it outputs each file on a separate line--not sure that's what you wanted.

Comment: @chrisd - No, not really. I need them on one line (part of a build script).

Comment: OK, the batch below will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to output them all on one line, as in the example. If so, here's one way:

test.bat

```
@echo off
set cmd=echo
for %%A in (%*) do call :Add %%A
%cmd%
goto:EOF

:Add
set cmd=%cmd% %1.txt
goto:EOF
```

Looks like this:

```
C> test 1 2 3 4 5
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt
C>
```

This doesn't handle the case where no parameters were provided very nicely (it would just say "Echo is on"), but an IF test would fix that.

Comment: Is it possible to modify that line for the case when something comes after 5.txt?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many arguments there are. It will loop through all of them. The `for %%A in (%*)` is a loop that runs once for each argument.

Comment: Use ECHO( instead of ECHO to eliminate "ECHO is off". Note that ECHO( is safer than the ECHO. form, even though it looks like it would cause problems with unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: @chrisd - I mean, something after 5.txt that is not an argument. I'm aware of loops :)

Comment: You mean you want to add something else after the argument list? Just add `set cmd=%cmd% whatever` after the `for` loop.